# Group Array by category

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I am facing problem In grouping array with the Key:- 
I have an php array Which has following elecment in it.

```
$array = array(
    '0' => array ( 'id' => 'food,Travel', 'names' => 'chimpanzee' ),
    '1' => array ( 'id' => 'food', 'name' => 'meeting' ),
    '2' => array ( 'id' => 'Z1', 'name' => 'dynasty' ),
    '3' => array ( 'id' => 'X', 'name' => 'chocolate' ),
    '4' => array ( 'id' => 'Travel', 'name' => 'bananas' ),
    '5' => array ( 'id' => 'Travel', 'name' => 'fantasy' ),
    '6' => array ( 'id' => 'Travel', 'name' => 'football' )
);
```

When I try with following code:-

```
$newarray= array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $newarray[$value['id']][$key] = $value;
}
```

I am getting below result Array Here food,travel is created another array but I want to please those to respective category "Food goes to food" and travel goes to travel"

```
 (
    [food,Travel] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => food,Travel
                    [names] => chimpanzee
                )

        )

    [food] => Array
        (

[1] => Array

                    [id] => food,Travel
                    [names] => chimpanzee
                )  
(
                    [id] => food
                    [name] => meeting
                )


        )

    [Z1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Z1
                    [name] => dynasty
                )

        )

    [X] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => X
                    [name] => chocolate
                )

        )

    [Travel] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Travel
                    [name] => bananas
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Travel
                    [name] => fantasy
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Travel
                    [name] => football
                )

        )

)
```

But I am want following result:- Food should Go to food category and travels  should go to travels category like:-

```
Array
(
    [food] => Array

    (
            // Food should come at food category 
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => food
                    [names] => chimpanzee
                )

        )

        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => food
                    [name] => meeting
                )

        )

    [Z1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Z1
                    [name] => dynasty
                )

        )

    [X] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => X
                    [name] => chocolate
                )

        )

    [Travel] => Array
        (
            ( // Travel should come at travel category
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => food
                    [names] => chimpanzee
                )

            )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Travel
                    [name] => bananas
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Travel
                    [name] => fantasy
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Travel
                    [name] => football
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Does the data come from mysql? If so you could do it in your query

Comment: yes data from database not mysql .. I am using cassandra where there is not group by option will be present

Answer (score 0):

When `id` has `,`, just `explode` it, check the [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bedb59f404b76c4dca5149d8c7d2552f514d0508)

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $k => $v){
    if(strpos($v["id"],",")) {
        $ids = explode(",", $v["id"]);
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $result[$id][$k] = $v;
        }
    }else{
        $result[$v["id"]][$k] = $v;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to make it complex, like some have suggested, use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

https://3v4l.org/jVK6j

```
$newarray= [];

foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    if(is_array(explode(",", $value["id"]))) {
        foreach(explode(",", $value["id"]) as $category) {
            $newarray[$category][$key] = $value;
            $newarray[$category][$key]["id"] = $category;
        }
    } else {
        $newarray[$value["id"]][$key] = $value;
    }

}

var_dump($newarray);
```

You could even remove `$key` since these will be auto incremented.

```
foreach($array as $value) {

    if(is_array(explode(",", $value["id"]))) {
        foreach(explode(",", $value["id"]) as $category) {
            $value["id"] = $category;
            $newarray[$category][] = $value;
        }
    } else {
        $newarray[$value["id"]][] = $value;
    }

}
```